# How not to import double rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a text file that gets updated every day with new data. But when I import that text in to SQL Server, it just add the same data so now the data is double in my table. How do I only import the new data?

I tried this code but it just deletes and reenters it again.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
INTO tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
FROM ems

    DELETE FROM ems

    INSERT INTO ems
        SELECT * 
        FROM tempdb.dbo.tmpTable

    DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
    GO
```

Comment: Which columns in the table(s) determine whether or not a record is viewed as a duplicate?

Comment: Kindly add some sample data.

Comment: 2018/06/03,15:06:59,1,25.01,0.879,2.75,2.49,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,27.94,2.2.2,-250.00,key,0,0,0
,GL45R-2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,58,2,

Comment: The data gets log per even so there is hundreds and thousands and it import each row double thats one row

Comment: You can truncate the destination table before inserting the data if the file is small enough to load as full otherwise you will need to lookup the records in the existing table before inserting them. how are you importing the data into table?

Comment: the data is import with this command, BULK INSERT (table name)
FROM 'C:\Users\test.txt' --location with filename
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r'
)

Comment: Try using`group by` on all columns which have duplicate records. I guess the first column gets updated to the time you insert the record. Try excluding that if that's the case in the `group by` clause.

Comment: there is hundreds and thousands of rows so i will have to group all of them

Comment: What about using unique indices? And why do you import the same data day by day?

Comment: Nico the data looks the same but its not the numbers will be change the date will stay the same for that day but that,s it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following might help:

```
SELECT All_columns, row_number() over (partition by all_columns_except_first_two order by col_1 desc, col_2 desc) as rownum
INTO tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
FROM ems
group by other_columns

DELETE FROM ems

INSERT INTO ems
SELECT * 
FROM tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
where rownum = 1

DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.tmpTable
GO
```

It will leave the latest record for an entry in the file (if the time fields are in first two columns).